# Kotlin JS doesn't add "new" keyword where needed

Tags: javascript, kotlin, google-visualization, kotlin-js

I am creating interactive infographics using Google Charts and Kotlin JS. This is snippet from [Quick Start Page](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start).

```js
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
<..>
var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
```

Here "new" keyword is used. I tried to rewrite this code using Kotlin.

```
val data = google.visualization.DataTable();
<..>
val chart = google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
```

But an error occurred saying that "new" keyword is missing in lines above. So Kotlin to JS compiler haven't added the keyword where they should be. Here is compiled JavaScript code.

```js
var data = google.visualization.DataTable();
<..>
var chart =  google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
```

Is there correct way to avoid the error without using js() function?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you also share the javascript code compiled from these kotlin lines?

Comment: @Ilya Ok, done it.

Comment: If I'm reading [this thread](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/is-there-a-way-to-use-the-new-operator-with-arguments-on-a-dynamic-variable-in-kotlin-javascript/6126) correctly, it looks like you need to use the `js` function for all native Javascript object creation anyway. Is your avoidance of `js` on principle, or did you see this type of call work without the `js` function elsewhere?

Comment: @JeffBowman JS object creation works correctly when used this way:  ```val request = XMLHttpRequest(...)``` is compiled to ```var request = new XMLHttpRequest(...)```

Comment: I  would guess it's because a JavaScript function can be called with and without `new`, meaning very different things, and KT doesn't know which you mean.

Comment: @ЕгорПономарёв Yes, but that's a [Kotlin class](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/org.w3c.xhr/-x-m-l-http-request/index.html), not an arbitrary expression (`google.visualization.DataTable`); as far as Kotlin knows, maybe DataTable is a plain function. Perhaps you need corresponding `external class` headers [as XMLHttpRequest does](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/js/src/org.w3c/org.w3c.xhr.kt), but even then it's unclear whether it would work with the built-in `google.visualization` namespacing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why the `new` keyword was not added is because `google` variable hadn't been added with `external` keyword. With this one Kotlin generates correct code.

```
external object google {
    object visualization {
        class DataTable
    }
}
```